# Kombu/Celery Publisher Subscriber

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, publish-subscribe, kombu

I have a very simple Django app. Currently, the app is consuming a RabbitMQ(cloudamqp) publisher queue. Here is the code for the consumer:

```
 from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue

 media_exchange = Exchange('media', 'topic', durable=True)
video_queue = Queue('video', exchange=media_exchange,  routing_key='video')

def process_media(body, message):
  print("welcome to consumer")
  print(body)
  message.ack()

# connections
with Connection('amqp://amqphost') as conn:
    # consume
    with conn.Consumer(video_queue, callbacks=[process_media]) as consumer:
        # Process messages and handle events on all channels
        while True:
            conn.drain_events()
```

if i put those code in **my_consumer.py** and execute from the terminal like this it works as expected.

```
$ python my_consumer.py
```

But if I put in **tasks.py** and put inside a task method it doesn't work. I was wondering if there is any way i can hook it up with celery worker and task. I'm running this celery command to turn on the worker

```
$ celery -A email_service  worker -l info -Q video
```